# How to add image watermark to images after uploading to website?

Tags: asp.net, watermark

My website runs asp.net with razor syntax i wanna place an image with transparent background to the image uploaded (in images folder at the website) let says its path (~/Images/photo4.jpg)

whats the easiest way to do it in c# ?

something like :[image]

Comment: You can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113900/c-sharp-add-watermark-to-the-photo-by-special-way And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870137/automatically-add-watermark-to-an-image